# Azure Function - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: azure, storage, azure-functions

Im running an Azure Function .NET Standard 2.0 and get following error:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in Function.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

[image: Reference]

The assembly file exist in the bin/debug folder. Been reading some threads about this but without a solution (https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/322#issuecomment-352233979), anyone know what to do?

I'm using code from another .NET Standard 2.0 project but all my projects have a reference to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 9.2.0.0 and that nuget package installed.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you remove that explicit reference? Functions SDK already references `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` of different version, so you get conflicts

Comment: I tried to remove the refence, bot in this project and another project where the code was init, still same error..

Comment: Hmm... delete bin-debug, rebuild?

Comment: Sorry no difference, reading the thread i posted indicate that it will require something more, but people stop posting in that thread in end of May so wonder if they solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add reference below to downgrade your storage reference explicitly.

`<PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="8.6.0" />`

See this [issue comment](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/821#issuecomment-391867397).

> This restriction (like many of the other assembly version restrictions we had with other extensions) is a temporary issue and will be addressed in upcoming preview releases.

This issue has been fixed in latest host [`2.0.11888`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/v2.0.11888-alpha), but built cli(tools to run functions) is not available yet.

**Update**

`2.0.11888` has been available to VS users.